# How to display bounding boxes permanently in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to display the bounding boxes of all object in my canvas permanently.

By default they shown only when they are activeObject.

I have read the Docs, but I still haven't find a solution.

Comment: Create a group and put a bounding box rect plus the object in the group.

Comment: You want to display just borders OR bounding boxes aligned with axes?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I want to display just borders.